# Is it haram to pray for good health of a disbeliever?

Tags: halal-haram, kuffar, health

Assalamualaikum, i actually wanted to know whether it is haram to pray for good health of a disbeliever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The religion of Islam is a religion of love and mercy. Yes, it is permissible to pray for a non-Muslim for health and wellness, but as long as he is not hating Muslims or harming Muslims, whether by word or deed.

Praying for his forgiveness of sins is haram
But praying for him guidance is not haram